# When and where to check on a Firebase user in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to figure out how to use Firebase.

I have  a config with an auth listener:

```
 onAuthUserListener(next, fallback) {
    // onUserDataListener(next, fallback) {
      return this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        if (!authUser) {
          // user not logged in, call fallback handler
          fallback();
          return;
        }

        this.user(authUser.uid).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            let snapshotData = snapshot.data();

            let userData = {
              ...snapshotData, // snapshotData first so it doesn't override information from authUser object
              uid: authUser.uid,
              email: authUser.email,
              emailVerified: authUser.emailVerifed,
              providerData: authUser.providerData
            };

            setTimeout(() => next(userData), 0); // escapes this Promise's error handler
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // TODO: Handle error?
            console.error('An error occured -> ', err.code ? err.code + ': ' + err.message : (err.message || err));
            setTimeout(fallback, 0); // escapes this Promise's error handler
          });
      });
    }

    // ... other methods ...
  // }
```

I have read the documentation about creating a listener to see if there is an authUser and have got this authentication listener plugged in.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session/Index';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase/Index';



const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };  
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser })
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        },
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    };  

    render() {
      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }
  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);

};
export default withAuthentication;
```

Then in the consumer component I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch,
    useRouteMatch,
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { Divider, Layout, Card, Tabs, Typography, Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon } from 'antd';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase/Index';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization, withEmailVerification } from '../Session/Index';




const { Title, Text } = Typography
const { TabPane } = Tabs;
const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;


class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
    loading: false,
  };




  onCollapse = collapsed => {
    console.log(collapsed);
    this.setState({ collapsed });
  };

  render() {



    return (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      { authUser => (  

        <div>    

                 <Text style={{ float: 'right', color: "#fff"}}>
                 {/* 
                    { 
                      this.props.firebase.db.collection('users').doc(authUser.uid).get()
                      .then(doc => {
                          console.log( doc.data().name
)                          
                      })
                    } 
                  */} 

        </div>
      )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>  
    );
  }
}

export default withFirebase(Dashboard);
```

It works fine the first time the page is loaded.

However, on a page refresh, the system is slower than the code and returns null error messages that say:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null (anonymous function)

I have seen [this article](https://javebratt.com/firebase-user-undefined/) which proposes solutions for Angular.

I can't find a way to implement this so that it works in react.

The article suggests:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user =>; {
  if (user) { this.userId = user.uid }
});
```

So, in my listener I tried putting if in front of authUser - but that doesn't seem to be an approach that works.

Any advice on what to try next to make a listener that lets firebase load the user before it runs the check?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are reading the uid?

Comment: What does 'the system is slower than the code' mean? Also, what is the problem with the solution you suggested? What error are you getting from your proposed solution?

Comment: @JoshPittman I mean the component loads before the user has been found in firebase (as described in the article I posted)

Comment: @CampbellMG - I added the firebase.js file where the auth listener config is set up to read the properties off the authUser. Then, in any component that is a consumer of the withAuthentication wrapper, can access the authUser listener

Comment: @Mel You can't speed up the firebase network call.  You can only load the code in question after the user has been found with a conditional. `authUser && this.user(authUser.uid).get()...` or you could use `if (user) {...}` like you suggested as your own solution.

Comment: @JoshPittman My own suggested solution did not work. That's why I asked the question. I'll try your other suggestion when I get back to my desk.

Comment: @JoshPittman - I don't understand your first solution. When I try replacing the authUser in the context consumer with { {authUser && this.user(authUser.uid)} - it throws an error - maybe your suggestion is shorthand for something obvious, but I can't see what that obvious thing is

Comment: It was shorthand for any kind of conditional, a ternary or an if statement. what error does it throw?

Comment: Okay - well I'll keep looking for a solution that I can implement somewhere. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 1):

Try [react-with-firebase-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-firebase-auth) this library.
This library makes a withFirebaseAuth() function available to you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

import withFirebaseAuth, { WrappedComponentProps } from 'react-with-firebase-auth';

import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const App = ({
  /** These props are provided by withFirebaseAuth HOC */
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithGoogle,
  signInWithFacebook,
  signInWithGithub,
  signInWithTwitter,
  signInAnonymously,
  signOut,
  setError,
  user,
  error,
  loading,
}: WrappedComponentProps) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {
      user
        ? <h1>Hello, {user.displayName}</h1>
        : <h1>Log in</h1>
    }

    {
      user
        ? <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        : <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
    }

    {
      loading && <h2>Loading..</h2>
    }
  </React.Fragment>
);

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();

/** See the signature above to find out the available providers */
const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};
/** providers can be customised as per the Firebase documentation on auth providers **/
providers.googleProvider.setCustomParameters({hd:"mycompany.com"});

/** Wrap it */
export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. This is not the objective of the question. It is a refresh problem. I'm about to try react useEffect instead of componentDidMount to try and solve the problem and will post a solution here if I find one that works.